# Need to find Actionscript 3.0 lib/framework/engine that works on mobile

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, frameworks

I have programming experience with Java and Actionscript 3.0 but for now Im looking for lib/framework or engine for ActionScript 3.0 since I want to make games for android and ios. This dosen't seems to be that easy.
I have tryed flashpunk, starling, citrus-engine. I like flashpunk but seems like it dosen't run good at mobile phones at all. And starling where kind of complex and confusing might be that I diddn't use enough time on it but before going any further I need to know what I shall do.

Answer (score 0):

I use Starling and Flash CS6 to publish games in App Store, Google play and Amazon store. It is relative easy if you use project with shared libs and different fla files to target all platforms.

Comment: Thank's for answer Azzy Elvul:) I think that's the best solution. Does starling have it own inbuild collision detection? Is it easy to use?

Comment: I'm not shure but I think it haven't. See this for collision detection.
http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-8-collision-detection/ 
http://wiki.starling-framework.org/tutorials/basic_collision_detection?s[]=collision